# Beam Side Input Pattern Logic Explaination

Tags: java, apache-beam

In the official Beam programming guide, it introduces the pattern we should use when we have a side-input. I am curious about why the pattern is like this. See below standard code as an example.

Looking at snip of code here:

```
      ParDo.of(
          new DoFn<Long, KV<Long, Long>>() {

            @ProcessElement
            public void process(ProcessContext c) {
              Map<String, String> keyMap = c.sideInput(map);
              c.outputWithTimestamp(KV.of(1L, c.element()), Instant.now());

              LOG.debug(
                  "Value is {}, key A is {}, and key B is {}.",
                  c.element(),
                  keyMap.get("Key_A"),
                  keyMap.get("Key_B"));
            }
          })
      .withSideInputs(map))
```

Beam has `.withSideInputs(map)` at the end of code to indicate there is side input in this block of code. In the mid of block, we have `Map<String, String> keyMap = c.sideInput(map);` **For me this is weird because we let the code know at end that we have a side input but we use it in the mid of the block. Why is that? Why we need to indicate at end but could use it in the middle?**

Attached is the entire example provided by Beam for using this pattern.

```
public static void sideInputPatterns() {
  // This pipeline uses View.asSingleton for a placeholder external service.
  // Run in debug mode to see the output.
  Pipeline p = Pipeline.create();

  // Create a side input that updates each second.
  PCollectionView<Map<String, String>> map =
      p.apply(GenerateSequence.from(0).withRate(1, Duration.standardSeconds(5L)))
          .apply(
              Window.<Long>into(new GlobalWindows())
                  .triggering(Repeatedly.forever(AfterProcessingTime.pastFirstElementInPane()))
                  .discardingFiredPanes())
          .apply(
              ParDo.of(
                  new DoFn<Long, Map<String, String>>() {

                    @ProcessElement
                    public void process(
                        @Element Long input, OutputReceiver<Map<String, String>> o) {
                      // Replace map with test data from the placeholder external service.
                      // Add external reads here.
                      o.output(PlaceholderExternalService.readTestData());
                    }
                  }))
          .apply(View.asSingleton());

  // Consume side input. GenerateSequence generates test data.
  // Use a real source (like PubSubIO or KafkaIO) in production.
  p.apply(GenerateSequence.from(0).withRate(1, Duration.standardSeconds(1L)))
      .apply(Window.into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardSeconds(1))))
      .apply(Sum.longsGlobally().withoutDefaults())
      .apply(
          ParDo.of(
                  new DoFn<Long, KV<Long, Long>>() {

                    @ProcessElement
                    public void process(ProcessContext c) {
                      Map<String, String> keyMap = c.sideInput(map);
                      c.outputWithTimestamp(KV.of(1L, c.element()), Instant.now());

                      LOG.debug(
                          "Value is {}, key A is {}, and key B is {}.",
                          c.element(),
                          keyMap.get("Key_A"),
                          keyMap.get("Key_B"));
                    }
                  })
              .withSideInputs(map));
}

/** Placeholder class that represents an external service generating test data. */
public static class PlaceholderExternalService {

  public static Map<String, String> readTestData() {

    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    Instant now = Instant.now();

    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("HH:MM:SS");

    map.put("Key_A", now.minus(Duration.standardSeconds(30)).toString(dtf));
    map.put("Key_B", now.minus(Duration.standardSeconds(30)).toString());

    return map;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Apache Beam model is an interesting hybrid declarative/procedural programming. When interacting with the SDK, you are building a directed acyclic graph of transform behind the scenes. There are special transforms (ParDos) that allow the programmer to add special logic that can't be captured with the Apache Beam primitives.

In the case of SideInputs, what this is declaring in the graph is kind of like a "Promise" or a "Future". You declare that this ParDo will receive in the future, at run-time, a SideInput which you can then use. This is why you can "use it in the middle" despite it being "declared" at the end of the ParDo; the code is only defining a node in the graph but not executing the graph itself.

If you want to see the technical specification for SideInputs you can read the [design document](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1lCIPzkopkEcRKBOvc7lQFWUAmQmRBqTbnT0v-KKtiC8/edit#heading=h.vsm77zumek69).

Comment: So useful and clear explanation  thank you